Can not access to HPE ILO from ESXI vm
I have an HPE Gen10 server with ESXi 8 installed on it. I assigned a static IP to the ILO: 192.168.100.100 on the shared LAN port. The IP of the installed ESXi on this host is 192.168.100.101.
I created a Windows VM and assigned it a network adapter with the default VM Network port group, giving it the static IP: 192.168.100.102. I can access the ESXi console and ping the IP of ESXi (192.168.100.101), but I cannot ping or access the ILO IP (192.168.100.100).
I have another pc connected via a wire to this server (with IP: 192.168.100.110), from which I can access all of these IPs, including the host, VM machines and ILO. Additionally, I can ping the IP of the connected pc from both the VM and the ESXi host.
My question is: How can I access the HPE ILO from a VM created on the ESXi installed on that server?
I appreciate any help.

You can't reach the ILO on a shared network port by using the "hosting" port (two logical ports sharing the same physical port / same hardware). "Workarounds": Using the dedicated ILO port and a short cable to a free NIC port (if you have a free one available) or just connecting the dedicated ILO port to the switch.

duplicate
